# Cryptic "A is not a function" error when using Lambda functions for Netlify with a Vue & Express app

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js, aws-lambda, netlify

I'm building a web app with Vue, which will use Netlify Lambda functions and Express.js as the server-side (making the app "serverless"). This is now possible with Netlify, and I am following their official guide: [How to run Express.js apps with Netlify Functions](http://How%20to%20run%20Express.js%20apps%20with%20Netlify%20Functions). I am also using the [Netlify Lambda plugin for Vue CLI](https://github.com/netlify/vue-cli-plugin-netlify-lambda) to integrate the lambda functions into my Vue build process.

I have a small lambda function called `server.js`. When this function is called, it will grab data from the Spotify API.

```
'use strict'; 

const serverless = require("serverless-http");
const SpotifyWebApi = require("spotify-web-api-node");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/search", (req, res) => {
    // function that searches for a song with the Spotify API
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/.netlify/functions/server', router);  // path must route to lambda

module.exports = app;
module.exports.handler = serverless(app);
```

This should work - it follows the pattern in the `server.js` file in [Netlify's official example repo for Express.js with Netlify Functions](https://github.com/neverendingqs/netlify-express). I create an Express app, add a `GET` endpoint called `search` to the Express API, and then export the Express app as the handler for the Netlify Lambda functions.

However, I keep getting this cryptic, vague error whenever I navigate to the url for the Lambda function: `TypeError: a is not a function`. I have researched this error and tried a bunch of the hotfixes and workarounds, but they haven't fixed the issue. Here is the full stack trace:

`{"errorMessage":"a is not a function","errorType":"TypeError","stackTrace":["i (/var/task/server.js:1:220)","Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/server.js:314:35760)","i (/var/task/server.js:1:220)","Object.e.exports.a.debug (/var/task/server.js:159:7043)","i (/var/task/server.js:1:220)","Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/server.js:159:5636)","i (/var/task/server.js:1:220)","Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/server.js:314:13004)","i (/var/task/server.js:1:220)"]}`

If this question does not have enough detail or you want to look at my config files or my exact function, feel free to explore the Github repo for my small web app: https://github.com/vintners/music-calc-app

Also, this is the URL for the `server.js` Lambda function on my Netlify site: https://happy-goodall-8bd7c9.netlify.com/.netlify/functions/server

Is my Lambda function set up incorrectly?

Comment: It would be really helpful to see the "stack trace" for that error. Since you don't have an `a` function in the code you've included, the error is clearly happening someplace inside of another function, and the stack trace from the error can help locate where exactly that is.

Comment: That's the problem: the stack trace is almost unreadable. See the answer above, I added it. Or navigate to the url and see it in the wild: https://happy-goodall-8bd7c9.netlify.com/.netlify/functions/server

Comment: Yep, that's pretty useless. I assume based on things like line 314, column 13004, that server.js is some sort of minified/webpacked file. either you're going to have to look in your webpacked file at the locations it's mentioning to see what's going on there, or maybe you can use the unminified code in lambda, or see if you can get source mapping working on your lambda [something like this maybe?](https://github.com/evanw/node-source-map-support) never used it, just googled `aws lambda node source map`.